# How to remove a remote branch ref from local

Tags: git

In my repo, there is one `master` branch for website source code and `gh-pages` for Jekyll generated static website code. `gh-pages` is very large because it is generated code, and its commit history will always only has one commit, because I have a Github Action that force push to new website code for every commit in `master`.

One day I accidentally run `git pull` instead of `git pull origin master` in my local `master` branch, so now `origin/gh-pgaes` ref is in my local repo too.

I want to know if there is a way to remove this `gh-pages` ref in local repo and all the git objects related to it to save space?

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/gh-pages
```

If you don't ever want to pull `gh-pages`, then you should update the remote's fetch refspec.

```
git remote set-branches origin master
```